# nhibernate mapping from fluent to mapping by code

Tags: c#, .net, hibernate, nhibernate

One `Country` has many `States`. One State belongs to one Country.
Mapping Country property in StateMap using fluent mapping was

```
public StateMap()
{
    ...
    References(m => m.Country).Not.Nullable();
}
```

what is nhibernate mapping by code alternative

should I simply map Country as property

```
Property(m => m.Country});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alternative to References is [Mapping-by-Code - ManyToOne](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-manytoone.html)

```
ManyToOne(x => x.Country, m =>
{
    m.Column("column_country");
    // or...
    m.Column(c =>
    {
        c.Name("column_country");
        // other standard column options
    });
...
```

The HasMany is [Mapping-by-Code - Set and Bag](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-set-and-bag.html)

```
Set(x => x.States, c =>
{ 
    c.Lazy(CollectionLazy.Lazy); // or CollectionLazy.NoLazy, CollectionLazy.Extra

    c.Table("tableName");
    c.Schema("schemaName");
    c.BatchSize(100);
    ...
```

The links provided above are the best place where to start observing the mapping by code